# Is it possible to not have a CSS rule inherit?

Tags: css

So I use this rule in the `body` selector:

```
body {
  text-align:center
}
```

and it inherits down to what looks like everywhere that I use text. Is there a way to tell CSS I **don't** want this rule to inherit?

I only want the body centered.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> and it cascades down to what looks like everywhere that I use text.

No, it doesn't. It is inherited. The cascade describes how multiple rule-sets which match a given element are applied, not how a value is copied from the parent element.

> Is there a way to tell CSS I don't want this rule to cascade?

The only way to stop inheritance is to set the value of the property to something other than `inherit` on the element you don't want to inherit it.

You could, for example, set it to left for all the child elements of the body (using [a child combinator](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#child-combinators):

```
body > * {
    text-align: left;
}
```

That said, the problem is likely to be better addressed by not putting inline content directly inside the body in the first place.

Put the content in a container element (a div if nothing with better semantics presents itself) and then centre the content of that element instead.

Answer (score 5):

Do this:

```
body {text-align: center;}       /* Apply to Body */
body > * {text-align: initial;}  /* Reset all styles */
```

AFAIK, the default value of `text-align` is `inherit`, which makes the above code obsolete. So, you can add something like this:

```
body {text-align: center;}       /* Apply to Body */
body > * {text-align: left;}     /* Reset all styles */
```

Comment: What does `> * ` mean?

Comment: @cadegalt That's the direct child / descendant selector.

Comment: All direct children I take it, wow I'm going to google it unless you have a reference.

Comment: `>` is the child combinator (which used to be called the child selector). `*` is the universal selector. There is no descendant combinator here (that is represented by a space character between two selectors). "Direct child" and "direct descendant" are not a terms used in HTML, all descendants in HTML are direct. It is much simpler than human families which can have such things as stepchildren and marriages.